# Dog keeps biting at this spot on his tail

Tags: dogs, health, biting

Am I worrying too much? I noticed the past day that he keeps biting at this one spot, and I noticed it was balding. I took a picture of it. Can anyone give me any ideas on if this looks normal or not? I tried to compare it to the rest of his skin on the tail but couldn't get past all the fur.

Picture of the spot he keeps biting: http://puu.sh/9DA69/217d1da5da.png

Answer (score 2):

Well, it could be as harmless as a really bad skin itch either from some allergen or fleas. Seems awfully localized, however, and one of the clinical signs of canine [obsessive compulsive disorder](http://www.petmd.com/dog/behavior/evr_dog_behavior_compulsive_disorder) is compulsive chewing a particular part of the body. While some of the OCD behaviors are relatively harmless, this one is much less so because it's effectively self-mutilation that could result in injury. However, not being a vet or specialist you can't take this as a diagnosis so you probably should have him taken in for a look-see. A vet is going to be able to confirm or rule out fleas, rash, OCD, etc.

Either way, what's happening is not normal and he needs to be examined.